# how to measure the similarity between images of different sizes

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to measure the similarity between two images of different sizes, the images are represented by color moments feature, when I want to measure the similarity between these two images using euclidian distance I get the error: Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.
For example:

```
distance=norm(color_moments(img1) - color_moments(img2));
```

img1 and img2 have different sizes, by the result their color_moments vectors have also different sizes which makes the comparison impossible. How can I solve this?

Comment: I think the color moments should give you the same size of vectors. The color moments describe the color distribution. There number should not depend on the image size

Answer (score 1):

Just resize the image with [imresize](https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html)